# Screenshot capture for multiple windows in python

Tags: python

Is there a way I can capture screenshots of multiple windows open in my PC at the same time through a python code? If I am able to specify which all windows to capture it will be good. I have tried capturing screenshot at regular intervals, for a single window using pyscreenshot module. It captures the screenshot for whatever window is open (primary screen). But what I wish to do is to capture multiple windows at the same time, not a single window. Can anyone help with this?